# Find $1/x^3+3/x^2+3/x$ when $x=4^{1/3}+2^{1/3}+1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Find $1/x^3+3/x^2+3/x$ when $x=4^{1/3}+2^{1/3}+1$.

I am not sure how to solve it. I believe it's a matter of lcm-ing and using formulas.

The answer however (after checking it on WolframAlpha is 1-- quite beautiful).

Comment: Please use MathJax; [here’s a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). In particular, if you don't know where to start, think about what techniques are related to the question so that others can better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

Use the fact that $(x+1)^3 = x^3+3x^2+3x+1$, so $(\frac{1}{x} + 1)^3 = \frac{1}{x^3} + \frac{3}{x^2} + \frac{3}{x} + 1$.

You can find $\frac{1}{x}$ by using the difference of two cubes.

Comment: An addition: Writing $x=a^2+a+1$, we get $x(a-1)=a^3-1=1$ since $a=2^{1/3}$, so $1+1/x=a$.

Comment: I know; you didn't need to spoil it for the OP.